# Difference between ng-model and ng-model-instant AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What difference between ng-model and ng-model-instant? When I can use ng-model-instant and ng-model?

Could you give me any example?

Thanks.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/fqG2vyQVxLk

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`ng-model-instant` was removed in one of the 1.0 release candidates, and `ng-model` now behaves that way. Before that 1.0 RC, `ng-model-instant` was triggered on every key press and `ng-model` on every blur. See [the changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/06d0955074f79de553cc34fbf945045dc458e064).

Answer (score 3):

`ng-model-instant` is deprecated.

> ngModelInstant directive is no more and ngModel behaves just as
>   ngModelInstant used to. This doesn't really break anything, just
>   remember to remove all ngModelInstant references from your template as
>   they serve no purpose now.

From [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-8).

It seems that from version 1.0.0rc4 and above ng-model-instant behave exactly like ng-model.

Comment: FYI your link points to an unrelated breaking change, it should be #breaking-changes-8!

Comment: It seems you can't permalink to those page anchors, it's now up to #breaking-changes-21 at the time of writing! I suggest just manually finding the breaking changes for the release: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1.0.0rc4

Answer (score 0):

Though the functionality of `ngModel` and `ngBind` attribute seems nearly same as both helps in binding data with element but there is a big difference between two. In actual both are totally alike to each other.

`ngModel` enables two way binding between view and model whereas `ngBind` only helps in showing data on element. Use `ngModel` with controls like `checkbox`, text which has value attribute and use `ngBind` with elements like `span` or `div` which has text attribute.

Comment: the question was about difference between ngModel and nogModel-instant.