# angular js : upload file with multipart/form-data by http post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js, multer

i am doing multiple file uploading. first share with you technologies using. front end: angular js and backend : node js. when i use following code it works fine for me.

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="http://localhost:3000/api/policy/upload/file" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Choose file
    <input type="file" id="pdfInp" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)" file-model="myFile" name="uploadedFiles">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

i am using multer for uploading files in node js. But whenever i am doing the same by calling a function instead of using action attribute, it fails. My angular code is following which is called on submit.

```
<form id="uploadForm" ng-submit="uploadFile(myFile);" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Choose file
    <input type="file" id="pdfInp" multiple onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)" file-model="myFile" name="uploadedFiles">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

$scope.uploadFile = function (files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', files);
    $http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/policy/upload/file', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined,
        }
    }).success(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }).error(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    })
}
```

please help me out.why file is not uploaded on calling function and pass files by formdata. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see you're using `ng-model-instant` which is very old (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005738/difference-between-ng-model-and-ng-model-instant-angularjs))...can you specify which version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: yeah its by mistake...we can remove it..btw m using jsv1.4.8

Comment: How did you solved I'm stucked right at the same point :( @RanjitSingh

Comment: Could you put contents of `files`? I just would like to see if it's valid or not.